# What do I need to share a partition for both Windows & Linux?

Tags: windows-7, windows, linux, ubuntu

I wand to use a partition and to be accessible for Windows 7 & Linux Ubuntu for read/write operations. Can anyone recommend me something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ubuntu can read/write to NTFS partitions (which are the default Windows 7 type).  So just create a new partition as NTFS with Windows 7, and then mount it with Ubuntu when you're using Ubuntu.

[Details here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions).

Summary: use ntfs-config under Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu Linux can read/write all the file systems Windows 7 can make, with the exception of exFAT.